# May I take a sleep immedietely after doing exercise?

Tags: exercise, bodybuilding, weight-gain, sleep

I'm currently working on my body building. I found that it is good to do some small exercises like weight lift and thandal on morning.

I’m waking at 5:30 am since I need to do some official work on that time (send an update mail to my US team) and I’ll drink a cup of water and then a cup of milk in empty stomach. Then, I’ll do the above exercise for 15 to 20 minutes. But, my office time starts at 10:am. So I’ll go for a small sleep after the excercise.

Is it good for health? Does it affect my weight gain process?

Comment: Yes, it is OK. Sleep is paramount for bodybuilding.

Comment: @ssteinberg, sleep immedietely after excercise is my question. is it ok?

Comment: Yes, there is no physiological reason I am aware of that would make it bad in anyway, on the contrary, it helps with recovery.

Comment: If I were you, I'd have more than a cup of milk before exercising especially given your other [question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/15184/milkhoney-helps-gain-weight) regarding weight gain.  You can't expect to gain weight if you are not fueling your training.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't do you any harm at all. If anything, it will probably be quite beneficial. Providing your nutrition is in check that is. After your workout, make sure you refuel your body/muscles with some good quality food containing proteins, carbs and fats. Then sleep.