# Milk+honey helps gain weight?

Tags: weight-gain, food, milk

I’m currently working on gaining weight to my body. I just want to know, adding honey to milk will helps for gaining weight or not?

Some said, adding honey with hot milk and cold milk differs from each other and adding natural honey is differ from [packaged ones](http://www.liondates.com/product_lion_honey.php).

My scenario is adding Packed honey with boiled milk. Does it helps gaining weight?

Comment: Adding honey to a hot milk is incorrect. To gain wait buy adding Ghee or Egg to your milk

Comment: There is no magic formula, you gain weight by increasing calories above the calories your burn each day.  Pretty simple.

Comment: You should specify whether you want to gain lean muscle weight, or if any weight will do (i.e. if you're trying to be a Sumo or some other equally tragic figure).

Comment: @MrBoJangles, I just want to increase my body weight to nrmal, I'm below the basic BMI level. :(

Comment: It will help you http://www.ekunji.com/health/how-to-gain-weight-fast

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It might help you gain weight, but you would have to drink a lot of it. Not to mention that weight would probably be fat - not muscle.

That said, why Milk and Honey? Drinking 5 bottles of Coke a day will help you gain weight as well - doesn't mean you should do it or that it's the correct or smartest thing to do.

Why don't eat some food - lean beef, with pasta - chicken and rice - lots of vegetables, salads, fatty fish like salmon and trout?

You're in a position where you have the opportunity to eat lots of nutritious foods which will benefit more then you know but you've chosen milk and honey.

Doesn't make sense to me. Each to their own though I guess.

Comment: Deserves upvote, don't have enough rep.

Comment: Now you do. 123.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be careful what type of calories to take "WHEN". Honey are sugars, fast carbs. If you use fast carb prior to your workout or during your workout, they will feed your muscles, help them to perform better and have a more effective workout that helps you gain muscle mass. If however you take any fast carbs post-workout, most of the excess carbs will help you gain the wrong kind of weight: fat.

The base rule for gaining weight in the most desirable distribution (high muscle-mass gain, low fat-mass gain) is to concentrate your carb intake into the period starting 1.5 hours prior to workout and ending half an hour prior to ending your workout. Concentrate protein intake to the few hours after your workout. Finally, concentrate fat intake in the period starting a few hours after workout and ending a few hours before the increased carb intake.

Basically you should get most of your resting calories from fat, most of your working out calories from fast carbs (lactose and honey are fine, but fructose might also be a good option) and have your protein intake set on 2g/kg body weight. Play around a bit with the amount of carb calories you take in before and during workout. You will want to have excess carbs so you can finish your workout at full throttle, but don't overshoot by to much or you will be gaining more fat than muscles. Your proteins are for repairing and growing your muscles post-workout and during the night. Finaly given that you wnat most of your resting calories from fat, you need to make sure your insulin levels have recovered from the pre-workout carb induces sugar rush.

Comment: +1 I'm interested by your mention of a 1.5 hour pre-workout carb timing window. I've seen several discussions about post-workout timing, but not pre-. Can you point me to any references? I'd love to do some reading.

Comment: The idea is that you need the carbs to be available 'during' your workout.If you start taking (slow)carbs 1.5 hours before your workout,they will be slowly released mostly before and during your workout.The carbs released before workout could in theory be used to top up your glycogen reserves while those that are released during your workout will (next to the fast carbs and stored glycogen)directly get used by your muscles.The idea is that as the end of the workout gets closer, the GI of any carbs used should go up as to not end up with to much excess carb release after finishing the workout.

Answer (score 1):

Will milk and honey help you gain weight? The simplest answer is **no**. Unless you are drinking them in large quantities frequently *(which wouldn't be healthy)*, you wouldn't gain longterm weight from them. 
 
You should drink those for their nutritious benefits and not as a weight-gaining gimmick. Lowfat milk contains protein and calcium, which can build your body and strengthen your bones. Honey is a natural sugar that has a lot of [medicinal and nutritional benefits](http://www.care2.com/greenliving/10-health-benefits-of-honey.html). 
 
To gain weight, do the same thing a weight-loss person would: Eat lean protein, vegetables, and fruits. Include complex carbohydrates in your diet and some protein shakes *(every now and then)*. 
 
Then, **lift weights**.*(your goal is to gain muscle weight and not fat weight, right?)*. There are many weightlifting programs online that you can follow *(check out [Starting Strength](http://startingstrength.com/) and [Strong Lifts](http://stronglifts.com/))*. ***Don't perform much cardio*** as they are meant for weight-loss, not weight-gain *(I would prefer you perform some cardio from time to time because they're good for your lungs and heart)*. 
 
This way, you can increase your weight without increasing your fat size; you really don't want to gain fat weight. 
 
Hope this helps.